# Can't connect to workgroup

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008

I have two computers in my workgroup. My laptop has Windows 7 on it and desktop has Windows Server 2008 on it.

I can ping and connect to the Windows Server 2008 from my laptop but I cannot ping or connect to my laptop from Windows Server 2008.

Both computers are in the same workgroup, and their IP addresses use the same subnet mask.

Does anyone know why I cannot connect to my laptop from the Windows Server 2008 machine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions and http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Don't you have any Firewall on your laptop that prevents traffics from the next station ?

Comment: Yes. The issue was actually firewall of windows 7 computer. Created a rule. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure Windows Firewall to allow all incoming connections.